# No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8

Tags: r, encoding

I just wrote a code in order to extract some data.

The script is working almost just fine. By almost, I mean that I can get the results that I want, but I have always the same issue in my console which is :

```
No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8.
```

The problem is that I'm running a loop with 900 lines, so I have 900 times the "No encoding supplied: defaulting to UTF-8."

Is is possible to get rid of it ? Does it have an impact on the process speed ?

Here is my code :

```
mykeywords <- readLines("mykeywords.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
mykeywords <- as.character(mykeywords)

my_user_agent <- "XXXXXXXXXXX"
PAA = list()
max_length = 0

for (i in 1: length(mykeywords)){
  url_to_check <- paste0("https://www.google.com/search?q=",mykeywords[i],"&amp;ie=utf-8&amp;oe=utf-8&amp;client=firefox-b")
  result_get <- GET(url_to_check, user_agent(my_user_agent)) %>% 
    htmlParse(encoding = "UTF-8") %>% 
    xpathSApply('//div[/*]/g-accordion-expander/div/div', xmlValue)
if (is.null(result_get)) {
    PAA[[i]]= NA
  } else {
    result_get = result_get[result_get != "" & !is.na(result_get)]
    PAA[[i]] = result_get
    if (length(result_get) > max_length) {
      max_length = length(result_get)}}}
```